# How to change facebook og:image to post image link?

Tags: social-network

For the facebook comments/share/etc I get the wrong thumbnail and as far as I've googled, it's due to the og:image meta tag. I'm using Drupal for Facebook module, is there a way to alter it? I found that I have to place 'rel="image_src"' somewhere, but where? At the image tag? And how can I do that using views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Metatags module supports OpenGraph meta data with token support, patterns, overrides for individual nodes and so on. It's a really handy module for this kind of stuff.

http://drupal.org/project/metatag

If you're getting the wrong image show up in Facebook you could point it to the correct image using this module's token support.

Comment: Ace. Glad to have helped. Would you mind marking this as the answer? Cheers.

Comment: @danbohea i added the token [metatag:image_src] but I don't know where this value is coming from? I did not specify this kind of value anywhere else. Please advise.

Comment: @Xeen may you please advise on how you made it work? Because I just can't make it to work, Mine is using views and the metatag for views, under advanced section was (image section) [metatag:image_src] which does not work.

Comment: I'd also like to know how you made it work, since this solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your HTML page, inside the `<head>` tag; this will tell Facebook to use this image when any page from your site is posted on Facebook.

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.example.com/facebook-logo.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement

```
hook_html_head_alter()
```

On the pages you like, alter the  output of those pages like

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7#comment-27259

There you can

```
dpm($head_elements)
```

and unset the previous og:image, or if you are in a node page you can load this node and display a field-image ...

This becomes handy when you are not on a node page, e.g. a Views page