# How to use metatag:image_src to share images on Facebook using the Service links module?

Tags: views

Image shared on Facebook via the [Service links](https://www.drupal.org/project/service_links) module is not showing up correctly when shared. I'm using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) with custom template to view this specific content.

Based on the Views configuration I can specify the image to be `[metatag:image_src]` in the metatag section. I have no idea where this syntax is going to get the image from, because I don't define this anywhere else, in the Views nor the Content type itself.

Another workaround I am looking at is to add a metatag tag in the head section via the `hook_html_head_alter()`. But I need more guidance on how and where to add this specifically, in detail.

The question about "[How to change facebook og:image to post image link?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60000)" is not enough information for me.
The issue about [Support for facebook "title" and "image_src" meta tags](https://www.drupal.org/node/916780) discusses the above.
I don't know how to patch using [Allow Views meta tags to "Use replacement tokens from the first row"](https://www.drupal.org/node/2143979).

I'm still digging through Drupal and no experience in module creation.

Anyone can point me to a more detailed solution regarding this issue?

I also created support request [Image not showing on facebook share](https://www.drupal.org/node/2387519) in the Service links module issue queue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the approach suggested in [Comment nr 1](https://www.drupal.org/node/2387519#comment-10064526) of [Issue nr 2387519](https://www.drupal.org/node/2387519), which is like so:

1. Install module [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) (easy to understand module). Use the module and make your configurations.
2. Clear the cache.
3. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object and click the "Fetch new scrape information" button to ping/update your meta tags to Facebook server.